# Xamarin: can't play video in table view cell

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avplayer, video-player

Hello fellow programmers, I am currently using this code im my TableViewSource:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = (RFVideoTBC)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(RFVideoTBC.Identifier(), indexPath);

    var url = NSUrl.FromString("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAGd-nev78g");

    AVPlayer player = AVPlayer.FromUrl(url);

    var playerViewController = new AVPlayerViewController();

    playerViewController.Player = player;
    playerViewController.View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 
                                                              0, 
                                                              cell.Frame.Width,
                                                              200);

    playerViewController.ShowsPlaybackControls = false;
    cell.AddSubview(playerViewController.View);

    player.Play();

    return cell;
}
```

Player seems to be ready, the URL confirms to the HTTPS-protocol, player status is "ready to play".

But all I get is a black canvas:

[image]

What is wrong with my code? When I restart Xamarin, clean and rebuild the application, there is sometimes an
activity indicator showing up for 3 seconds, but the black canvas with the disabled play button returns afterwards.

Can't figure out why, tested playing a video on iOS 9 simulator and a my iPhone.

Comment: Does the player work on its own outside the UITableView?

Comment: Hi hankide, unfortunately not

Comment: Your URL is pointing to a YouTube page. Have you tried using a Url that resolves to an actual video file like a m4p file?

Comment: Yes, I did, I also switched off transportSecurity in order to use HTTP-links. Meanwhile I rewrote my code like this: 


   `AVAsset asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"));
   AVPlayerItem item = new AVPlayerItem(asset);
   player = new AVPlayer(item);
   playerViewController = new AVPlayerViewController();`


In my DidSelectRow-Method I check if player status ist ReadyToPlay, then I present the playerVideoController. The play button ist not disabled anymore, but canvas stays black and video is not playing.

Comment: I would recommend you to try setting up `AVPlayer` outside `UITableView`, and note that iOS can play only one instance of `AVPlayer` at a time

Comment: I even tried a local mp4-file outside the tableView, it does not work. Can't imagine of problems like this when I was working with Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this: (don't forget to switch off the TransportSecurity). It's a mess, but it works.

```
    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (player.Status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ready to play");
            player.Play();
        }
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (RFVideoTBC)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(RFVideoTBC.Identifier(), indexPath);

        player = AVPlayer.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"));
        var layer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer(player);
        layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
        layer.VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspect;

        layer.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(16,
                                              75,
                                              cell.Frame.Width - 32,
                                              200);

        cell.ContentView.Layer.AddSublayer(layer);

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Are there any gotchas that you need to look out for when putting players in table view cells? Like in `prepareForReuse()` or the like?